# javascript datalist remove item

Tags: javascript, datalist

I try to dynamically remove an item from a datalist with the following code but it's not working.
I tried some different ways but same bad result.
Any idea to solve the issue :

I tried :

```
App.removeOptionDatalist= function (objRemoveoption){
  for(var x=objRemoveoption.children.length; x>0 ; x--){
        objRemoveoption.remove(objRemoveoption.children[x]);
  }
};
```

OR

```
App.removeOptionDatalist= function (objRemoveoption){
  for(var x=objRemoveoption.length; x>0 ; x--){
        objRemoveoption.remove(x);
  }
};
```

And some others ...

Comment: Please define "it's not working".

Comment: @Teemu nothing is deleted of the datalist

Comment: Have you taken a look at the console? Did you find any error messages there? Was the function ever called?

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." with the first solution

Comment: and nothing with the second

Comment: Interesting, your'e getting an error message about failed `removeChild` method, but you're using `remove` method. How is that???

Comment: no I tried to different ways (see description) in the first i get the error and in the second no error

Comment: A tip: Think very carefully, what actually is `x` when you first time use it in the body of the loop. If you've no clue, log its value to the console ...

Comment: @Teemu i logged x on console (var x=objRemoveoption.children.length) and I have all the values I want but for remove each child nothing is deleted with objRemoveoption.removeChild(objRemoveoption.children[x]); and i have the following error message : "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Comment: Umh... The value of `x` equals to `objRemoveoption.children.length` at the time the execution enters the body of the loop. There's no such member in `objRemoveoption.children` ... Collections are array-like objects, the last index in a collection is `collection.length - 1`. After you've solved this, it's good to know, that `children` is a live collection reflecting the real time state of the DOM, i.e. it is updated whenever you remove an element from the DOM, and the length of it changes ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove an item from datalist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002168/remove-an-item-from-datalist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found in this stack question [Remove an item from datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002168/remove-an-item-from-datalist).
Use the clearChildren function